How do I connect wires to this type of connector block?
In the image of the back of my entry-phone panel below, terminals B1 and B2 (IN) previously had wires attached but two of them broke off, so there is a little bit of copper wire in each terminal, with green and blue wires coming out of the wall dangling, disconnected.  I need to remove the little bits of copper that are stuck inside the terminal block and strip off a bit of length from the wires then reattach, but I can't see how to free up the terminal.  If it was a screw I'd unscrew it, or a lever-type I'd unflip the lever, but I can't see how to get into this one.  It seems the grey plugs are pushed in, do I need a tool or something to get them out or how do I get the wires back in to their connectors please?


Each wire insertion hole on the left has a corresponding hole on the right with a little white piece of plastic in it. That piece of plastic may be attached to a spring-loaded tab in the wire insertion hole which could keep pressure on the wire.
Try inserting a small flathead screwdriver into that right-side hole and push the white plastic toward the wire strip gauge sign on the right. Or try pushing in on the white plastic. This may allow the wire to come out.
As Huesmann suggests in a comment below, the mushroom-looking part in the middle may also be the thing that needs to be pushed.
You might need the unit off the wall and held horizontal so the broken wires can fall out.

Might it also be the kinda mushroom-shaped bit (with the slot across it) right in the middle of the terminal block that needs to be pushed on?

That's a very good possibility as well, thanks!

Thanks @Triplefault and Huesmann - it was the "mushroomy" grey thing that I had to press in and that released the copper bit, and allowed me to push in the newly stripped wire end.  All working well now.

Thanks for the feed back! @Huesmann comes in for the win!
